# Is it possible to use Quartz 2D to make a UIImage on another thread?

Tags: ios, ios5, grand-central-dispatch, quartz-2d

I want to move some code that takes a couple seconds to generate a UIImage on another thread, but im getting a context error when using

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,false,0);
```

before calling the dispatch to generate the image saying "invalid context 0x0" for each operation i try to do. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[*What's New in iOS: iOS 4.0*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29) says this:

> - Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. Specifically:
>
>   - The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads.
>   - String and image drawing is now thread-safe.
>   - Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.

It sounds like you tried something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,false,0);
dispatch_async(someQueue, ^{
    [UIColor.whiteColor setFill];
    UIRectFill(0, 0, 20, 20);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        self.imageView.image = image;
    });
};
```

That won't work because each thread has its own stack of graphics contexts (starting in iOS 4.0).  You need to do it like this:

```
dispatch_async(someQueue, ^{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,false,0);
    [UIColor.whiteColor setFill];
    UIRectFill(0, 0, 20, 20);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.imageView.image = image;
    });
};
```

#### UPDATE

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) for `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and other UIKit graphics functions now says

> In iOS 4 and later, you may call this function from any thread of your app.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `UIColor` says

> Color objects are immutable and so it is safe to use them from multiple threads in your app.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `UIFont` says

> Font objects are immutable and so it is safe to use them from multiple threads in your app.

**However**, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for the UIKit `NSString`-drawing additions says

> The methods described in this class extension must be used from your app’s main thread.

So you must **not** try something like `[@"hello" drawAtPoint:CGPointZero withAttributes:attrs]` from a background thread.

Comment: The docs says that UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions should be called on the main thread only, but I use it in background thread without having any problems.. Do you have any idea why the docs says it should be called on the main thread?

Comment: @graver I don't know for sure.  I suppose it does something like `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` if you pass 0 for the scale, and maybe that's not thread-safe.

Comment: Everything `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` does, you can do pretty easily by setting up a `CGBitmapContext`, adjusting its CTM, and pushing it with `UIGraphicsPushContext`.

Comment: @robmayoff could be it. The interesting part is that `UIKit` drawing is thread-safe as for iOS4.0+, but if you call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` on the main thread it will add the context to the stack on the main thread, but the background thread's context stack would be empty and you can't use it with `[UIImage drawInRect:]` for example. We may need to ask Brad Larson maybe...

Comment: @robmayoff Now, after a couple of days investigating this, the only logical reason is that the documentation about this is **wrong** and it's perfectly fine to call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` in another thread...

Comment: Just in case anyone else runs into this: I was originally getting an exception when running this on a background thread, but I eventually learned that was because I was using `[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]` to generate the image. Once I switched this to `afterScreenUpdates:NO`, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) say:

> You should call this function from the main thread of your application only.

So calling it on another thread is not a good idea.

You could try using [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) instead, and calling `CGBitmapContextCreate()`.

Comment: I agree, if you use this in another thread, you will get it trouble somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily operate using a `CGContext` to produce a `CGImage` while on a secondary thread.

Back on the main thread, create a `UIImage` from the `CGImage`. Note that `UIImage` is an immutable container type - this should not result in a deep copy of the image data.